# Finding day of week given date (no libs or package imports allowed)

Tags: java

I want to create a Java Program that takes a date as input (27,2,2019) and print out what day it was. I am just assuming the usage of Gregorian Calender only. The reference is 1,1,1 which is a Monday. I am unable to complete this. Can someone help me out please. I also took leap years to account. Also, in this project, I am not allowed to import any packages so I should do it normally.

```
public class sortday
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        sortdayoftheyear(1,1,2019);
    }
    public static void sortdayoftheyear(int day, int month, int year)
    {
    final int [] months = {31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31};
    {
        final int monthnum = 12;
        int totaldays=0;
        int newmon = month-1; //find which month it is 
        int monthdays = months[newmon]; // find days of the month

    for (int i = 1; i < year; i++)
    {    
        if (i%100 != 0 && i%4 == 0 && i%400 == 0) //check for leap year
            { 
                totaldays = i*366;
            }
        else
            totaldays = i*365;

    }

    totaldays += (day) + (newmon*monthdays);


    if (totaldays%7 == 4)
        System.out.println("Sunday");
    if (totaldays%7 == 5)
        System.out.println("Monday");
    if (totaldays%7 == 6)
        System.out.println("Tuesday");
    if (totaldays%7 == 0)
        System.out.println("Wednesday");
    if (totaldays%7 == 1)
        System.out.println("Thursday");
    if (totaldays%7 == 2)
        System.out.println("Friday");
    if (totaldays%7 == 3)
        System.out.println("Saturday");

    System.out.println("It had been " + totaldays + " since January 1,AD");
}

    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is in the `newmon*monthdays` expression. If the current month is February, that doesn't mean that January also had 28 days in this year.

Comment: newmon does month -1 which goes back to the array and gets the right monthdays. Could you clarify more on what you said?

Comment: If homework, please say so.

Comment: It isn't homework but the teacher said this program was just like an extra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be more than one bug in your code. I have spotted:

- Each time through your `for` loop you are assigning a new value to `totaldays`. In this way only the last time through the loop has any effect in the end. I believe you intended every iteration to contribute.
- As yole said in a comment, `newmon*monthdays` is incorrect for the total number of days in the first `newmon` months of the year. I even think that for February 13 your are counting 13 + 1 * 28, which can’t be right. One suggestion is you loop through the months and add up their lengths.
- If the entered year is a leap year, you are always counting 28 days in February. You want to count 29 sometimes. An auxiliary method to determine whether a year is a leap year would come in handy.
- If your reference date of January 1, 1 is a Monday, I think you want to print this when the modulo operation in the end yields 1. You are printing `Thursday` in this case.

I can’t tell if there may be more.

Issues without functional consequences that you should nevertheless want to fix include:

- You are not using the constant `monthnum`, so delete it.
- You have a superfluous set of braces around the code piece from the mentioned constant down to `System.out.println`. Delete those too.
- Get your indentation right so you and I can read your code.
- When writing code for others to read (including Stack Overflow users), respect the naming conventions. Call the class `SortDay` or `FindDayOfWeek`. The method `sortDayOfTheYear` or `printDayOfWeek`.